# How do I re-use a variable with a different reference type?

Tags: java

For instance

```
int hello = 10;

bool hello = true;
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to re-use variables or change them

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why do you think you want to?

Comment: this will prone to a compilation error in `java`, because u can't declare two variables with the same name `hello`. better to use `object` data type to perform that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the type of a declared variable in java.

One workaround is to use the `Object` class in java. For example:

```
Object value = 10;
value = true;
```

The problem with this approach is that you have to be sure about the type of the variable while casting otherwise it will throw [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html). For example:

```
Object value = 10;
boolean boolValue = (boolean) value; // will throw exception at runtime
```

Comment: But this is almost certainly a *bad idea*.

Comment: @chrylis yes it could be a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Reference name should be unique across the scope.

Java is strictly type language and you cannot change it's type once declared however you are allowed to do this in loosely typed languages like Javascript, but in Java, No.

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot use same variable name to more than one reference, In spite If you need the most you can use "_hello" if its very necessary to use the variable with same reference name. but you can use same variable name in different methods.